# Override retry attempts with spring cloud stream kafka bindings consumer and DLQ enabled

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud streams with kafka bindings. The consumer is configured using spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.function configuration and DLQ is enabled.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.consumeTest-in-0:
    consumer:
        batch-mode: false
        ackEachRecord: true
        dlqName: test.file.error
        enableDlq: true
        dlqProducerProperties.configuration.key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        dlqProducerProperties.configuration.value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        maxAttempts: 5
        backOffInitialInterval: 5000
        backOffMaxInterval: 5000
```

When, I consume a message from a topic, and an exception occurs, I see that it retries 3 times, and sends the message to DLQ. I have configured with maxAttempts to 5 but I am unable to override the default value of 3.

I am using spring kafka (2.7.8) and spring cloud (2020.0.4).
How can I override the retry attempts and backOff interval params?

I noticed if I add the params at default consumer level (as below), they are picked, but not at function bindings level:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer:
    maxAttempts: 5
    defaultRetryable: true
    backOffInitialInterval: 5000
    backOffMaxInterval: 5000
    backOffMultiplier: 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it under `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeTest-in-0.consumer.maxAttempts=5` instead of your spring.cloud.stream.**kafka**.bindings.consumeTest-in-0.consumer.maxAttempts=5.

---

See here: [Common Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_common_binding_properties)